# Why flutter creates new frames when nothing changes

Tags: flutter, dart

There are no rebuilds or state changes, nothing changes on screen, but in Flutter Performance window shown that new frames are constantly being created. Why are they created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of processor, app needs processor power every second to be run. So new frames constantly build.

For example:- if you have a phone which has low powered processor and graphics render, you will see frame drops.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is responding to the GPU vsync signal, it is what triggers the Flutter build process.